# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeArray' and 'str'

Tags: python, xlsx

```
Dataset = "/content/Meteo.csv"
Dataset = pd.read_csv('Meteo.csv', encoding='latin-1', parse_dates=[['DATE', 'TIME']])
print(Dataset)

Solar = pd.read_excel(Dataset + "Demand.xlsx")
Solar.head()
```

[csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aT68NkfeeykyLyXkqtehRgmSFmL-_TsA/view?usp=sharing)
[xlsx file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o00k7aqoa9AWvG-VVcTzN0TqT82ocgHO/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113725198561674157107&rtpof=true&sd=true)

The error occurred "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeArray' and 'str'" when I tried to run the cell

```
Solar = pd.read_excel(Dataset + "Demand.xlsx")
Solar.head()
```

Comment: You have set a path in your first line for Dataset, but then overwrite  the variable with what you read from the csv the very next line. Dataset + "Demand.txt" therefore means you are trying to add a dataframe to a string which doesn't make sense. Should the second line variable only be Data

Comment: @GalodoLeste So how should I change my coding?

Comment: Its not clear from your code what you want to do with the dataframe you read from the csv (you don't seem to use it anywhere except to just print it), You need to either delete your second line if the data is not being used or change it to data =  pd.read_csv('Meteo.csv', encoding='latin-1', parse_dates=[['DATE', 'TIME']]). If you then want to print it, your print statement should be print(data).

Comment: @GalodoLeste the data will be used to calculate energy consumption. [my coding] (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eggSu96fgJS8xJMjw-Xm-KRCn6tkTItG?usp=sharing) and I referred to this coding but replaced it with my own data [reference coding] (https://github.com/hectoramirez/Predicting_energy_consumption/blob/7570eb089aebbcc288697c5a745a052f56a6f8cc/Consumption_energy.ipynb)

Comment: Then you can make the adjustments I suggested above to change the dataframe variable to data instead of Dataset. Just remember to use this new variable later in your code whenever accessing that csv data.

Answer (score 0):

Here the main problem is, you're redefining the `Dataset` variable and it is being replaced with a `DataFrame` object in second line of your code. You should try renaming second `Dataset` to something else.

```
dataset_path = "/content/"
data_frame = pd.read_csv(dataset_path + 'Meteo.csv', encoding='latin-1', parse_dates= 
[['DATE', 'TIME']])
print(data_frame)

Solar = pd.read_excel(dataset_path + "Demand.xlsx")
Solar.head()
```

Comment: the data will be used to calculate energy consumption. [my coding] (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eggSu96fgJS8xJMjw-Xm-KRCn6tkTItG?usp=sharing) and I referred to this coding but replaced it with my own data [reference coding] (https://github.com/hectoramirez/Predicting_energy_consumption/blob/7570eb089aebbcc288697c5a745a052f56a6f8cc/Consumption_energy.ipynb)

Comment: In your colab repo, there are no files that you are using in code. So you should upload them first inside content folder.